# How to make my program say that I'm close or far from the answer and then to input it again? C#

Tags: c#, if-statement, random, console-application, do-while

Here I have the program that selects random number for me to guess. How can I make it now to say that number is close or far away from original random selected by the program?

```
using System;


namespace higherlower_guesser
{
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {


        Random rnd = new Random();
        int randomNumber = rnd.Next(0, 100);


        bool answerCheck = false;
        int guessAttempts = 0;

        
        while (answerCheck == false)
        {
            Console.Clear();
            Console.WriteLine("Take a guess.");
            guessAttempts++;
            int enteredValue = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
            if (enteredValue == randomNumber) 
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Congratulations, the number in mind is {0}. You've had {1} attempts", randomNumber, guessAttempts);
                answerCheck = true;
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
```

Comment: What exactly does "close" or "far" mean?

Comment: What constitutes a number being "close"?  Maybe  `Math.abs(enteredValue - randomNumber) < closeDistance`  What do you need to know?  What's stopping you from doing what you want to do?

Comment: Also consider what would happen to your program if I entered "twelve" or 二

Comment: @Liam by close or far I mean when Random element selects the number that I need to guess while I run the program and when I enter the number that isn't selected by the program it needs to tell me if I'm close to it or far from the number I guessed

Comment: So is 3 close to 1 or far? What about 7000?

Answer (score -1):

You need to define what "close" and "far" are for your app. You can do something like:

```cs
const int CloseRange = 10;

if (enteredValue <= CloseRange) { /* we are close! */ }
else { /* we are far! */ }
```